# Django timezone wrong insertion with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, timezone

I am trying to save record in mysql by passing the current local time. django is either adding time to my current time zone or it subtract the time by 5:30 hrs. i have tried the following

```
content = {
        'status' : 1,
        'responseCode': 42,
        'time' :  timezone.now(),
        'another': timezone.localtime(timezone.now()),
        'zone' :  request.session.get('django_timezone'),
        "message" : datetime.datetime.today()
        }
```

Response:

```
{ 
  "status": 1,
  "responseCode": 42,
  "zone": null,
  "another": "2016-04-01T18:01:25.668+05:30",
  "time": "2016-04-01T12:31:25.668Z",
  "message": "2016-04-01T18:01:25.668"
}
```

I want to save the current time which is **2016-04-01T18:01:25.668** into DB but it will still save **2016-04-01 12:31:25**

Django Query :

```
refundObject = TblRefund(schedule_id = 1923,transaction= transObject,response = "test",date =  datetime.datetime.today())
```

I have set the timezone in settings.py file as :

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the format of MySQL datetime field is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fraction]'. You should convert your time to this format and store offset in additional field. About another ways you can read [here](http://billauer.co.il/blog/2009/03/mysql-datetime-epoch-unix-time/).

Comment: If format is the problem why is it storing the UTC time correctly i.e **2016-04-01 12:31:25**

Comment: b/c server converts it to own time, look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: i run this command and it returns me system as time zone which means my local time zone of Asia/Kolkata **SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone** which is correct